# Print to XPS without a Save As dialog

Tags: vb.net, printing, xps

How can I save an xps file by printing to a virtual printer without using the Save File As dialog? When I call the print method, a dialog automatically pops up asking the user to specify the file name and path. This only works when creating brand new files; it throws an error 'you do not have permission to write to that file...' if I attempt to overwrite an existing file. Anyways, I want the user to be able to specify the file name in my own dialog, not the one that is autamatically called by the printDocument's Print method.

```
Public Event PrintPage As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler
Private WithEvents Doc As New Printing.PrintDocument

Public Sub SaveXPSFile()
    Doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
    Doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "C:\Users\POConnell\Documents\t.xps"
    Doc.Print()
    Doc.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles Doc.PrintPage
   'drawing commands go here
End sub
```

Comment: That's why I switched to PDF's in the end. There are several nice PDF SDKs out there and free ones too.

Comment: I wanted to use PDF's but I can't. It wasn't my choice...

Comment: Not all computers have the `XPS` driver and then only a browser can open the file. This makes no sense over a widely used `PDF` file type.

Comment: So since I do have to use XPS, is this possible?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Was hoping someone else could help you if it was.

Comment: Lou Klauders answer here works:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182696/silently-use-microsoft-xps-document-writer-printer-to-create-xps

Answer (score 4):

It's a couple of months late, but here we go.

2 questions, two answers.

Question 1: 
How can I save an xps file by printing to a virtual printer without using the Save File As dialog?

Answer 1: You were close. I think you're looking for

Doc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
Doc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "C:\Users\POConnell\Documents\t.xps"

Here is my implementation:
(Legal paper size, landscape mode)

```
        Using prn As New PrintDocument
            With prn
                .PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
                AddHandler .PrintPage, _
                   AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
                .DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = landscape
                .DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = New PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400)
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\temp\Log.oxps") Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\temp\Log.oxps")
                .DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
                .DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "C:\temp\Log.oxps"
                .Print()
                RemoveHandler .PrintPage, _
                   AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
            End With
        End Using
```

As you can see, I use the oxps file format, but it should still work just the same for you.

Question 2: it throws an error 'you do not have permission to write to that file...' if I attempt to overwrite an existing file.

Answer 2: Check if the file already exists prior to printing the file, and delete it if it does. Of course it will fail attempting to create a file that already exists.

For some reason using My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile is faster than the traditional Kill() and System.IO.File.Delete, which both require the thread to sleep for ~1-200ms prior to recreating the file, or else a different access denied error will occur.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!