# SILENT conversion of PDF to XPS with "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, xps

I need to convert a bunch PDFs to XPS documents programmatically (in C#). Therefore, I tried to call several command line tools:

- AcroRd32.exe (Adobe Reader)
- SumatraPDF.exe (neat portable tool)
- PDF2Printer for Windows 10
- and many, many others.

However, none of them seems to support functionallity to specify a filename for the generated XPS, which **causes the "Save-Dialog" to pop-up on call**. I am looking for a complete silent way to convert a PDF to XPS without any user interaction. Furthermore, I wish to use only tools that are free for commercial use (without any AGPL licensing). Any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Btw, I already stumbled over this hack, which is not satisfying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182696/silently-use-microsoft-xps-document-writer-printer-to-create-xps

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following lib supports to convert pdf to xps and specify file name for generated xps file but with limitations: http://freepdf.codeplex.com

```
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    doc.LoadFromFile("FileName.pdf");
    doc.SaveToFile("FileName.xps", FileFormat.XPS);
```

Comment: That "free" version is actually a limited commercial version which they spam all over the internet.